# Journey Contact Evaluation of evaluate only New records

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am creating a Journey. As an entry source I have a DE which is updated daily with an automation.
I set in my journey in the Contact Evaluation of evaluate only New records, and I selected Re-entry only after exiting.
The record that has already taken the journey when it exits the journey does not re-enter because I have set of evaluate only the new records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evaluation of 'New records' is described here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5

If a record (Contact) has already entered and exited the journey before and has been added to the entry data extension again, this record will re-enter the journey. To prevent this from happening choose either:

1. Set the re-entry option to 'No re-entry'
2. Manage in the audience (daily automation) that records can only enter once in the data extension

Comment: I want it to re-entry of the journey. it's just a confirmation that I have set currency only for new records.
As it is no longer a new record.
Is it more correct to put all records in the schedule?

Comment: With these settings existing records which are updated will not re-enter the journey. Setting the evaluation to 'all records' is a bit overkill. The you would need to exclude or filter almost all contacts each time the automation runs. I would look into a setup where the contact is added to the data extension again, so it will be evaluated as a new record. Make sure that the primary key of you data extension allows for this behavior (e.g. by adding a date field).